# Breaking down a JavaScript Banner Slider

Tags: javascript, function, banner

I recently asked a question about this 'simple' slider, I would like to delve a little deeper. Here's the script:

```
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#slides .slide');
var currentSlide = 0;
var slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide, 2000);

function nextSlide(){
    slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide';
    currentSlide = (currentSlide+1)%slides.length;
    slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide showing';
}
```

So what I'm getting is:

- `currentSlide` is given a `0` value, when it has this value it's given the `slide` class
- That value is changed to `1`
- The remainder of that new value and the total amount of elements inside the `.slides` container is found and assigned to currentSlide variable
- Then any element inside the slide variable that is using that currentSlide variable is given both `.slide` and `.showing` classes

**Am I following this right?**

If I am, which I'm pretty sure I'm not, how does the function loop through the different slides without a loop function?

I thought I understood this more than I clearly do so any explanation would be a big help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is with this line:

```
currentSlide = (currentSlide+1) % slides.length;
```

So if we assume `slides.length` equals `3`, then `(currentSlide+1) % slides.length` evaluates to `0` on the third time around and resets, like this...

```
1 % slides.length // 1
2 % slides.length // 2
3 % slides.length // 0
```

So it reads more like this:

```
// Get the currentSlide and set the className to 'slide'
slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide';

// Set currentSlide to the next slide, i.e. 1, 2, or 0
currentSlide = (currentSlide+1)%slides.length;

/*
   currentSlide is technically the next slide at this point, so
   it's actually getting the next slide and setting the className
   to 'slide showing'. The next slide will be slide 0
   on the third time round.
*/
slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide showing';
```

**The above code executes every 2 seconds**, using `setInterval(nextSlide, 2000)`

Hope that makes sense! :)

Comment: Sorry this line is really confusing me and I'm not sure why I can't grasp it. So the line with the modulo isn't finding reminders? It's just adding an increment each interval and not allowing the increments to be >= 3? If that's the case why is the modulo operator used? How does the remainder finder do this?

Comment: It's just how the mod operator works. The best thing to do is open up a console (e.g. chrome devtools) and things out like 1%3 or 2%3... you'll see how it works! But yes, you're right, you could do the same thing by just checking if the increment is more than 3 :)

Comment: Ah I see. So if I divide number A by number B and number B is greater than number A, it'll just return number A? That seems to be what's happening.

Comment: Yup, you got it! Because number A can't divide, so the remainder is number A.

Comment: Hello again Daniel, I had a follow up question if you get chance. How come the interval has to be put into a variable? Can't I just call the command and link it to the relevant function? IE `setInterval(nextSlide, 2000);`

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the function `nextSlide()` doesn't loop through the images on itself, it just sets the class of currentSlide to 'slide' and the next slide(currentSlide+1) to 'slide showing'.  `setInterval(nextSlide, 2000)` is what makes the function go through all the images, this interval calls the nextSlide function after every 2 seconds.

So to start:

currentSlide is equal to 0.
slideInterval calls nextSlide() after 2 seconds.
It sets className for slide 0 to 'slide' and increments currentSlide to 1.
It then sets className for slide 1 to 'slide showing'.
Now slideInterval calls nextSlide() after 2 seconds but now it starts with currentSlide equal to 1.

Answer (score 1):

The first line of your code puts all of the elements with a `.slide` class inside a javascript array. Now indeed we need to find some way of looping through all of the slides.

The line `setInterval(nextSlide, 2000);` makes sure that the `nextSlide` function gets called  after 2000 microseconds. Normally there should be another `setInterval(nextSlide, 2000);` call inside your `nextSlide` function that makes sure that the nextSlide function gets called again in 2 seconds. That way we create a kind of loop. Maybe there is a `setInterval(nextSlide, 2000);` call inside the`nextSlide` function in your original script. It's absolutely essential. Otherwise we will not have a loop.

The `nextSlide` function hides the current slide and displays the next one. Inside the function a counter `currentSlide` is incremented. That's what causes the loop.

What's inside the `nextSlide` function?

```
slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide'; 
// remove the showing class so the slide with the index 'currentSlide' no longer shows

currentSlide = (currentSlide+1);
// increment the counter so it points to the next slide

slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide showing'; 
// add the showing class to this slide, so this slide is now showing.
```

Now we have to add one thing. We have to make sure that our counter returns to the first slide when we run out of slides. We use the % modulo operator for that. [Modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) is used when we want numbers to "wrap around" upon reaching a certain value. (The wikipedia article has a nice clock example).

We want to add 1 to the currentSlide counter and we want it to wrap around the total number of slides (= the length of the slides array):

```
currentSlide = (currentSlide+1)%slides.length;
```

Comment: Hi snwclone, could you explain how the function is doing to place the elements with .slide class in an array, which part creates the array? I thought I had to do ....array [1, 2, 3,].... to create an array?

Comment: The function Document.querySelectorAll returns a list of DOM elements.  You can think of it as an array. See https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Answer (score 0):

The `setInterval()` method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals (in milliseconds).

**The setInterval() method will continue calling the function until clearInterval() is called, or the window is closed.**

so `nextSlide{}` is call every two seconds.

`nextSlide()` must be contains the logic to increment the slider

Answer (score 0):

You're following well, but you skipped an important line: `setInterval(nextSlide, 2000)`. What this line does is execute the `nextSlide` function once every 2000 milliseconds (2 seconds).

The `nextSlide` function doesn't run when it is defined, but when it is executed by `setInterval`. Your analysis is right for what the function does on the first pass (when `currentSlide` is set to 0). After that, `currentSlide` will be 1, 2, ... The three lines of the function do the following:

- Set the class of the current slide to `slide`.
- Increment the `currentSlide` variable (the remainder stuff is so that it loops back to `0` when it gets past the end of the available slides)
- Set the new curret slide's class to `slide showing`.

This will happen once every 2 seconds.